# Calculate the distance between two integer Lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, coordinates

I am using C# and I have two `list<AACoordinate>` where each element in these lists represents a 3D point in space by x,y and z.

```
 class AACoordinate
    {
        public  int ResiNumber { get; set; }
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }
    }
```

Each list can **contain 2000 or more** points and my aim is to compare each point of list1 to all the points of list2 and if the distance is smaller than a specific number I keep a record of it. at the moment I am using **foreach** to compare each element of list1 to all of list2. This is quite slow because of the number of points. Do you have any suggestion to make it fast?

my loop is:

```
 foreach (var resiSet in Program.atomList1)
        {
            foreach (var res in Program.atomList2)
            {
                var dis = EuclideanDistance(resiSet, res);
                if (dis < 5)
                    temp1.Add(resiSet.ResiNumber); 
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you share foreach loop body?

Comment: @sll: It's slow because comparing every point against every other point is an `n^2` operation. It's like doing a selection sort.

Comment: You are describing a n*n solution. Can you be clearer about the 'keep it' criterion?

Comment: You might be best to post your whole foreach loop for us to look at to see your methodology.

Comment: @sll since there are 2000 or more points in each list, it's 2000*2000 items to check

Comment: You may get some purchase out of a [Bounding volume hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) or [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: Your problem is similar to the closest pair of points problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem. There are several discussions of it here on SO.

Comment: There could be some micro optimizations to how you check for the distance, e.g. Don't take the square root of the sums, but rather square the tested distance (which you can do in advance). Also if any of the linear distances (e.g. x2 - x1) is larger than your tested distance, then no need to calc the 3 dimension distance. But all changes should be benchmarked.

Comment: Mhhh I don't think this problem is directly solveable with the Closest pair of points problem. He need the list of nearest neighbours of two lists, and in 3 dimensions.

Comment: @Salvatore: I said that it's *similar*, not exact. And the addition of a third dimension doesn't change the complexity of the problem to any great extent. As the article says: "the problem may be solved in O(n log n) time in an Euclidean space or Lp space of fixed dimension d."

Comment: A small aside, the proposed algorithms assume a "single-space". He probably needs to merge the two lists and operate on the whole set of points (each with a source-list designator), throwing out results for same-list distances.

Comment: Yes, and as I say the only way to go that I can think of is using kd-trees (best solution) or quad trees (ok solution).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a little complicated to implement, but I don't have any other ideas than this:

To lower down the computational complexity probably you have to use some data structure like KD-Tree or QuadTree.

You can use a KD-Tree to do nearest neighbor search, and this is what you need.

1) You build your kd-tree for the first list in O(n log n). This must be done in a single thread.

2) For each item in your second list, you do a lookup in the kd-tree for the nearest neighbor (the nearest point to the point you are looking for), in O(m log n). If the distance from current point to the nearest found point is less than your delta, you have it. If you want you can do this step using multiple threads.

So at the end the complexity of the algorithm will be O(max(n, m) * log n) where n is the number of items in the first list, m is the number of items in the second list.

For KD-Trees, see:

See http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/software/kd/  this seems a good implementation, in java and C#.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/KDTree.aspx

For quad trees, see:

See http://csharpquadtree.codeplex.com/

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadTree.aspx

And of course, look on Wikipedia what is a quadtree and a kd-tree

Consider that (2000 * log base 2(2000)) is about 21931.5

Instead 2000*2000 is 4000000, a big difference!

Using a parallel algorithm, if you have 4 processors, the normal O(n*n) algorithm will require 1000000 per processor, and I guess, it will be still too much if you need something fast or almost real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel Libraries where you can find [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx).
[Paralel Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/dbb4e493-7b12-4a9c-b500-b567dce0eca8/)

Comment: Parallel processing gives you, at best, linear speedup. His algorithm is quadratic.

Comment: not sure parallel will help: since the complexity is m*n, a small increase in m or n will defeat the effort...

Comment: Than hee need a Custom Solution ,but for sure parallelism must be present there ,maybe using Threadpool.

Comment: @Cody he brobably better need to reduce the complexity in someway

Comment: @FelicePollano yes :) That is so true. In Italy we don't like quadratic algorithms, lol :)

Comment: @Salvatore Yes is true is a common mistake found in computational geometry problems, choosing the unoptimized algo and thinking that brute force will do. Of course when the correct algo is choosed parallel would eventually help

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compare each element of list1 with each of list2, you won't get rid of the nested for. But you could speed it up using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your current method checks each ordered pair in L x R, a simple O(n^2) algorithm. A couple of ideas come to mind.

First, you can try splitting each of the two arrays into, say, cubes of side equal to your maximum distance; then you'd only have to compute distances between elements in L and R if they are no more than 1 cube away. This is still O(n^2) in the worst case, but if your points are much farther apart on average than your maximum distance, you can save on a lot of spurious comparisons here.

Second, you can micro-optimize how you're doing the distance function. You never need to use sqrt(), for instance; comparing the squared distance to the maximum distance squared is sufficient. Also, you can avoid doing integer multiplications to get the squared distance if you first check whether |dx|, |dy| or |dz| satisfy certain properties (i.e., are already bigger than the maximum distance).

Parallelization, as mentioned by the other posters, is always a good bet. In particular, a sophisticated parallelization + boxing strategy (outlined in the first suggestion) should make for a particularly scalable, efficient solution.

Comment: Your first idea is quite similar to the Quad Tree concept :) but quad trees split in a recursive way.